# conditional formatting pivot table vba

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I would like to do some conditional formatting in a pivot table and make sure that when the pivot fields are changed, my formatting stays pertinent to what needs to be formatted.

Here is the beginning:

So far I have 2 columns in my dataset: account# and sales.  Problem I encounter is that my oPvtItm is empty. The "for each" loop is therefore doing nothing.

```
Sub condformat1()

Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim oPvt As PivotTable 
Dim oPvtItm As PivotItem

Set ws = ActiveSheet 
Set oPvt = ws.PivotTables("pv1")


For Each oPvtItm In oPvt.PivotFields("sum of sales").PivotItems

    If oPvtItm > 100000 Then
    oPvtItm.DataRange.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If 
Next

End Sub
```

Once this is solved, I would like to categorise my account (ex. group a,b,c). which might be either a row or column. (lets make it a column to make it simple). I would therefore be willing to analyse only sales of account group "a".

Comment: Have you tried using actual Conditional Formatting?

Comment: yes, but what will you do when you remove a field, or change it of place??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found what I was looking for:

```
    Sub condformat2()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim oPvt As PivotTable
Dim oPvtItm As PivotItem
Dim abc As String


Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set oPvt = ws.PivotTables("pv1")
Set oPvtDataField = oPvt.ColumnFields(1)
abc = "a"

For Each oPvtItm In oPvtDataField.PivotItems
    If oPvtItm = abc Then
        For Each cell In oPvtDataField.PivotItems(abc).DataRange
            If cell.Value > 100000 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Thanks to Doug as well as the author of those sources:

http://www.databison.com/how-to-read-data-from-pivot-table-using-vba/

http://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/

Comment: Ah, you found the Peltier reference! I meant to mention that. Very good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, I'd consider using actual Conditional Formatting instead of VBA. However, here's some code that will do what you requested:

```
Sub condformat1()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim oPvt As PivotTable
Dim oPvtDataField As PivotField
Dim cell As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set oPvt = ws.PivotTables("pv1")
Set oPvtDataField = oPvt.DataFields("sum of sales")

For Each cell In oPvtDataField.DataRange
    If cell.Value > 100000 Then
    cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That shows to have worked for me. Now how to solve my second question: my accounts are separated into 3 groups: a,b,c. I want to highlight only the group a ?  And what is the problem with pivotitems, I am confused? I tried this and its not working: `For Each cell In oPvtDataField.PivotItems("b").DataRange`